# .htaccess rewriting on django?

Tags: django, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site running on pynton django and I am trying to keep accessible some urls of it, while having a index.html showing.

I've tried to rewrite my .htaccess file but without results. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.html [L] </IfModule>


RewriteRule ^music/preview/listen$/(.*)$ http://example.org/music/preview/listen/$1 [L,R=301]
```

thanks  a lot.

Comment: what does "without results" mean exactly? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen?

Comment: yes i get internal server error

Comment: You've got various things in there that aren't spaces, which might be causing your problem.

Comment: Sorry I understand this is not a tutorial place, but can you be more specific? So that i now what to look for.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've got some issues with syntax, it looks like some of your newlines are missing and you have a malformed regex at the end.  Try cleaning it up:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^music/preview/listen/(.*)$ http://example.org/music/preview/listen/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Note that the `^music/preview/listen$/(.*)$` isn't valid, you can't have two `$` "end of string" characters.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm really struggling here. I still get internal server error. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @user2834426 also, dunno if you were copy/pasting, but I cleaned out the non-ascii whitespace characters that were probably disagreeing with apache